# Watchdog don't work with Atmega328PB

Tags: arduino-nano

I have a code that is working fine using WatchDog timer to auto reset in case something goes wrong, but now i got a arduino with **ATMega328PB**, and the old code just don't active the watchdog.

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>

wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    delay(1000);
}
```

This is the code to test, but the reset that should happen just doesn't happen.

In the datasheet say that the watchdog still there to use, but i have no idea how to active it now.

Comment: have a look at some of the tutorials that are available on the web

Comment: I didn't find no tutorials for the 328PB model

Comment: section 15.8 of https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega328PB-Automotive-Data-Sheet-40001980B.pdf

Comment: I already saw the example in the datasheet, but I couldn't compile it, is there any other option?

Comment: `couldn't compile it` ... what does that mean? ... what error did you get?

Comment: For example `__watchdog_reset();` there are 3 functions that I don't know how to replace or implement to keep the code functional, and there is also how to set the watchdog time